# Windows 7 merge two hard disk into one

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

I have two usb external hard disk and I want to know if I can merge them
as it had one hard disk and thus the SO see them as one hard disk.

Are there tools to do that or can I do with Windows builtin tool?

Comment: See this http://www.ehow.com/how_6804011_tie-external-hard-drives-one.html

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to buy an enclosure! Is there a software solution?

Comment: I'd strongly advise against doing a software RAID on external drives especially. You then have 2 points of failure.

Comment: -1 ??? why? I think it's a good question! There is really no reason to have a -1...

Answer (score 2):

Windows built-in diskmgmt.msc does only support merging partitions from the same physical hard drive.

The only way to achieve that using only out-of-the-box software would be to use diskmgmt.msc to mount your drives as folders in your system drive.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: They are called NTFS Mount Points, if the OP wants to sreach for more details on that.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_Mount_Point